# How to get list of all exchanges with xpath to google sheets

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Try to get a list of cryptocurrency exchanges from `coingecko` 2nd page into my google sheet.

To get a result like:

```
Tokenize
Bibox
Vebitcoin
...
```

Try to make it with.

```
IMPORTXML("https://www.coingecko.com/en/exchanges?page=2", "//*[contains(text(),' exchange')]")
```

As a result, get Error:
`Imported content is empty.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modified xpath?

#### Modified xpath:

```
//span/a[contains(@href,'/en/exchanges/')]
```

and

```
//span[@class='pt-2 flex-column']/a[contains(@href,'/en/exchanges/')]
```

#### Modified formula

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//span/a[contains(@href,'/en/exchanges/')]")
```

- In this case, the URL of `https://www.coingecko.com/en/exchanges?page=2` is put to the cell "A1".

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- The list of cryptocurrency exchanges can be retrieved by the modified xpath. But in this case, it seems that the values of `Tokenize`, `Bibox` and `Vebitcoin` are not included.

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of all exchanges, you can also use the following formula :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTDATA("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/search?locale=en&img_path_only=1"
));"select * WHERE Col1 starts with ""name""");"name:""(.+)"""))
```

Output (~ 8000 elements) :

[image: Exchanges]